# How to get a document after adding a document in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**What I'm trying to do**

I wanna get a document after adding a document.

**Index.js**

```js
var item = Firebase.storeItem({ itemName });
console.log(item);
```

**Firebase.js**

```js
storeItem = async ({ itemName }) => {
  this.itemsCollection.add({
    name: itemName,
  })
    .then((docRef) => {
      docRef.update({
        id: docRef.id,
      });
      docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        return doc.data();
      });
   });
};
```

**Problem**

In Firebase.js, it returns `doc.data();`, but console.log in Index.js outputs

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

How can I get a document?
I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices.

Comment: What happens if you remove docRef.update({ id: docRef.id,}); from code?

Comment: @Maycon Mesquita Thanks. Nothing changed if I removed ```docRef.update({ id: docRef.id,});``` :(

Comment: Try using arrow function instead 'function': docRef.get().then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      }).catch((e)=>{ console.log(e) });

Comment: You're not chaining promises correctly.  `then` just returns another promise that resolves after the promise that it returns finally resolves.  It doesn't make the original promise synchronous.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I see. Thanks. So how can I return ```doc.data()```?